# NDSolve giving me an error:-NDSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of -1.22474-3 (x[t]^2+y[t]^2) z[t] in the first argument

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am reallyt trying hard to get through it. I tried every soltion avialable online. Nothing works for me. When I solve first two equations x'[t] and y'[t], mathematica works fine and results are fine. But when I add z'[t] equation it gives me an error described in the following. z'[t] equation is required to put some constraint on the model I'm working on. Can anyone please help me to get it work somehow.? ASAP.
The code and the error is as shown below....

```
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == (-Sqrt[3]/Sqrt[2]*(0.5*y[t]^2 + 0.5)) - 
      3/2*x[t] (1 + x[t]^2 + y[t]^2), 
    y'[t] == -Sqrt[3]/Sqrt[2] 0.5*y[t]*x[t] + 
      3/2*y[t] (1 - x[t]^2 - y[t]^2), 
    z'[t] == -3*z[t] (x[t]^2 + y[t]^2) - 0.5*Sqrt[6],
    x[-7] == 0.00015, y[-7] == 0.00025, z[-7] == 0.999}, {x, y, 
    z}, {t, -7, 0}];
Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. %], {t, -7, 0}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotPoints -> 200, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"x[t]", "y[t]", "z[t]"}, Scaled[{0.1, 0.5}]]]
```

During evaluation of In[17]:= NDSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of True in the first argument {(x^[Prime])[t]==-Sqrt[(3/2)] (0.5 +0.5 y[<<1>>]^2)-3/2 x[t] (1+x[t]^2+y[t]^2),(y^[Prime])[t]==-0.612372 x[t] y[t]+3/2 y[t] (1-x[<<1>>]^2-y[<<1>>]^2),True,x[-7]==0.00015,y[-7]==0.00025,z[-7]==1}.

During evaluation of In[17]:= ReplaceAll::reps: {NDSolve[{(x^[Prime])[t]==-Sqrt[(3/2)] (0.5 +Times[<<2>>])-3/2 x[t] (1+Power[<<2>>]+Power[<<2>>]),(y^[Prime])[t]==-0.612372 x[t] y[t]+3/2 y[t] (1+Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>]),True,x[-7]==0.00015,y[-7]==0.00025,z[-7]==1},{x,y,z},{t,-7,0}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.

During evaluation of In[17]:= NDSolve::dsvar: -6.99996 cannot be used as a variable.

During evaluation of In[17]:= ReplaceAll::reps: {NDSolve[{(x^[Prime])[-6.99996]==-Sqrt[(3/2)] (0.5 +Times[<<2>>])-3/2 x[-6.99996] (1+Power[<<2>>]+Power[<<2>>]),<<4>>,z[-7]==1},{x,y,z},{-6.99996,-7,0}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.

During evaluation of In[17]:= NDSolve::dsvar: -6.99996 cannot be used as a variable.

During evaluation of In[17]:= ReplaceAll::reps: {NDSolve[<<1>>]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.

During evaluation of In[17]:= General::stop: Further output of ReplaceAll::reps will be suppressed during this calculation.

During evaluation of In[17]:= NDSolve::dsvar: -6.96479 cannot be used as a variable.

During evaluation of In[17]:= General::stop: Further output of NDSolve::dsvar will be suppressed during this calculation.

Comment: The code as you posted it worked for me without a problem. Have you tried running it in a fresh kernel? Perhaps there are some previous definitions messing things up

Comment: Please write a short and representative title. Include more details in the actual post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did u try quitting Kernel ? Your code just works fine or i did not understand the error...

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I just did what you mentioned and it simply worked.